# Modifying js function to merge pic from webcam and capturing screen contents using html2canvas or any other similar function

Tags: javascript, php, html2canvas

At present we have the following js function to take picture from webcam live feed at regular interval:

```
var takepicture = function() {
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
if (width && height) {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
    data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);
    props.webcampicture = data;

    var wsfunction = 'quizaccess_proctoring_send_camshot';
    var params = {
        'courseid': props.courseid,
        'screenshotid': props.id,
        'quizid': props.quizid,
        'webcampicture': data,
    };
}
```

Now, I have learnt that html2canvas can be used to grab screen and convert it as a picture through:

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
document.body.appendChild(canvas)});
```

Now I want to merge the two pictures into single one pass it as 'webcampicture' for further processing. Both pictures to be taken whenever these functions are called and finally return the variable 'webcampicture' as a single one like in the following picture:

[image: final image]

Is it possible to achieve using html2canvas or any other tools?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Capturing the whole desktop screen or active  window within from js or php is possible through screen share or get.media().